# Motivation for introducing $A^{\prime} := \frac{1}{\left|G \right|} \sum_{g \in G} \Delta(g^{-1}) A \Delta(g)$ in representation theory proof

Tags: representation-theory, motivation

Assume $\left|G \right|= \left| G \right| \cdot 1_F$ is invertible in $F$. Let $\Delta:F \to GL_n(F)$ be a representation and $U \subseteq F^n$ be an $F$-subspace that is $\Delta$-invariant. Then there exists a $\Delta$-invariant $F$-subspace $V \subseteq F^n$ such that $F^n= U \oplus V$.

Proof. Let $u_1, \ldots, u_r$ be an $F$-basis of $U$ and extend it to an $F$-basis $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ of $F^n$.
Let $A \in \text{Mat}_n(F)$ be defined by $Au_i = u_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,r$ and $Au_i=0$ for $i=r+1,\ldots,n$.

We set $A^{\prime} := \frac{1}{\left|G \right|} \displaystyle \sum_{g \in G} \Delta(g^{-1}) A \Delta(g)$.

Question $1$: What is the motivation for introducing $A^{\prime}$? It seems to pop up out of nowhere (Its use in the proof in not confusing, just not sure where it comes from)

Then we have:
(i). $A^{\prime} u = u$ for every $u \in U$.

(ii). $A^{\prime} x \in U$ for every $x \in F^n$.

(iii). $A^{\prime} A^{\prime} x = A^{\prime} x$ for every $x \in F^n$

(iv). $A^{\prime} \Delta(h) = \Delta(h) A^{\prime}$ for every $g \in G$.

Question $2$: I understand how the text proves all except (ii). It states, to see (ii), note that $A \Delta(g) x \in U$. 
I can understand that $A \Delta (g) \in \text{Mat}_n(F)$ and $x \in F^n$, so $A \Delta (g) x \in F^n$, but why in $U \subseteq F^n$? (Edit: No longer need explanation, answered in comments)

Comment: For (ii), look at the construction of $A$ in terms of basis vectors: every vector in the range of $A$ is a linear combination of $u_1,\ldots,u_r$ and thus belongs to $U$.

Comment: @ErickWong, Oh right, I feel silly now. Thanks, I get why (ii) holds now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The point is that $G$-homomorphisms $M \to M$ are exactly the same thing as elements of $\hom_F(M,M)$ on which $G$ acts trivially.  Notice that in $FG$, for any $x\in G$, $$x \sum_{g \in G}g = \sum_{g \in G}g.$$ So given *any* $FG$-module $N$ and $n \in N$, the element $\left(\sum_{g \in G} g\right)n= \sum_{g \in G} gn$ is either zero or spans a trivial submodule. That weird looking thing is what you get by applying $\sum g$ to the element $A$ of the $FG$-module $\hom_F(F^n,F^n)$ (think about the definition of the module action on $\hom_F$), so it is a $G$-hom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm giving a presentation to my fellow undergrads and unfortunately I don't think most of them will know what modules are. Would you mind expanding on "applying $\sum g$ to the element $A$ of the $FG$-module $\text{hom}_F(F^n, F^n)$?

Comment: you can change this into the language of reps if you like by saying $\sum_g\Delta_N(g) N$ is always an invariant subspace of $N$ on which $G$ acts trivially, and explaining how $\hom_F(F^n,F^n)$ naturally carries a rep if $F^n$ does.  But the whole thing will be an exercise in why the module language is nicer :)

Comment: to answer your question, "applying $\sum g$" to $m \in M$ in your language results in $\sum \Delta(g)(m)$

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: my earlier comment about invariant subspaces is misleading, and it's too old to edit.  Either $\left(\sum_g\Delta_N(g)\right)N$ or $\{\sum_g \Delta_N(g)(n): n \in N\}$ is the invariant subspace on which $G$ acts trivially.